# Asset Studio (in Android Studio): purpose of the Google Play Store icon?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-icons

I am trying the Asset Studio to generate the icons for my app.

Here is the Asset Studio doc : https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio

Nevertheless, I am not sure to understand what is the role of the "Google Play Store" icon generated by this Asset Studio.

Will this icon (that is then included in my bundle) will replace my icon on Google Play ?

I see in the Legacy tab, that I can select Google Play Store Icon => Generate => No. What is the impact on my app (and Google Play icon that can be seen by the users) if I select 'No' ?

By the way, the Asset Studio show many kinds of icons : circle, squirle, rounded square, square, full bleed layers, legacy icon... What is the purpose of each type of these icons ? Where are they used ?

Comment: in terms of the `circle, rounded square, square, full bleed layers, legacy icon`, on android you can customize your settings so that all your icons take on any of those shapes. So your icon can appear in several different ways on peoples phones depending on their settings

Answer (score 1):

When you generate an asset using the Asset Studio, the Google Play Store icon option just has it generate a PNG sized and shaped for the Google Play Store listing of your app, in addition to creating the assets for the app itself. The icon isn't uploaded to Google Play or anything for you; it will just appear inside your app folder, and it would be up to you to then upload it accordingly. If you don't plan on using this asset as your Play Store icon, then you can just uncheck this option. But if you don't it won't really affect you anyway, you'll just have an extra unused asset in your app you'll want to delete